# laravel 5.1 I want to create new users being logged in as admin

Tags: laravel

I am creating multiuser application with laravel 5.1 , I want admin to login and register new users.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own user registration controller. You can make any checks you need to perform in your controller's methods. Here is a sample of how to achieve this.

```
class RegisterUsers extends Controller{
public function __construct(){
    //only authenticated user can access this Controller
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
public function getRegister(){
    //check if user is admin -> load view for your registration page
}
public function postRegister(Requests\RegisterRequest $request){
   //check if user is admin -> create your user
}
}
```